# Filter records using JSON function for JSON array

Tags: sql, json, mariadb, json-query

There is one table where data stored in JSON format.  I need to find how many records are there where Quote Required.

JSON

```
[{"id":14,"desc":"Job is incomplete.","quote_required":"Yes"}, 
 {"id":14,"desc":"appointment need to rebook","quote_required":"Yes","start-date":"2021-11-20"}]
```

I am trying to achieve about using below `JSON_CONTAINS()` and `JSON_EXTRACT()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)   
  FROM `products`   
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( JSON_EXTRACT(submit_report, "$.quote_required"), '"Yes"' )
```

But I am getting 0 results here

Answer (score 0):

You can search for each element of the array whether having `quote_required` equals to `Yes` through use of index values starting from 0 upto length of the array minus 1 by generating index values with recursive common table expression such as

```
WITH recursive cte AS 
(
  SELECT 0 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS value
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < ( SELECT JSON_LENGTH(submit_report) - 1 FROM `products` ) 
)
SELECT SUM(JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(submit_report, CONCAT("$[",n,"].quote_required")),
                                      '"Yes"')) AS count
  FROM cte
  JOIN `products`
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d0ae666986721db6fc8ab61e2d28bb6c)</kbd>

Comment: Can we create a query without a recursive function?

Comment: @DarshanBaraiya another method to create dynamic content might be accomplished by using [metadata tables](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=198b340b496bf622d3a6c847f6a35ba1).